# Angularjs select option using angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to implement the AngularJS material implementation in my code and I'm stuck with a select option. Using AngularJS "base" my select option was this:

```
<select ng-model="search.filter" ng-options="data.description for data in search.getItmes.data" ng-change="search.initParams();"></select>
```

Now, using AngularJS material I can't understand what value pass... I try in this way but it's not working:

```
<md-select placeholder="Choose" ng-model="search.filter" ng-change="search.initParams();">
   <md-option ng-repeat="item in search.getItmes.data" value="{{item}}">{{item.description}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

It shows me the options correctly but the value it's not passing the value.

Comment: is getItmes only a typo in your example?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? By the way, i think that the problem is the structure of the ng-option (data.description for....) with that "for" the problem..something is missing passing from the simple angular select option to angular material..but i don't know what!

Comment: in your example, you have getItmes, not getItems

Comment: i solved just changing value with ng-value

Answer (score 0):

Update yr md-option as below.
You pass selected value to yr ng-model with "ng-value" inside md-option.

```
<md-select placeholder="Choose" ng-model="search.filter">
    <md-option ng-value="item" ng-repeat="item in search.getItmes.data">    
         {{item.description}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```